# ios safari attach pdf using email share

Tags: ios, safari

i am working on a PHP web application for mobile devices (iphone), the application will generate a pdf which can be viewed within ios safari browser, and is it possible to click the share button of the pdf page in the safari menu bar in the bottom and send the pdf file in email?